# How to calculate total of certain input type in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form which has some drop down dynamically created . Its like

```
1. Main question 
    a . Sub Question dropDown
    b . Sub Question dropDown
    c . Sub Question dropDown
2. Main question 
    a . Sub Question dropDown
    b . Sub Question dropDown
    c . Sub Question dropDown
```

The class name of each Drop down is like this

```
<select class="dropdown dec_MT004" name="MT004_percentage[]" data-placeholder="weightage">
  <option value="">Select</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
  <option value="20">20</option>
  <option value="30">30</option>
  <option value="40">40</option>
  <option value="50">50</option>
  <option value="60">60</option>
  <option value="70">70</option>
  <option value="80">80</option>
  <option value="90">90</option>
  <option value="100">100</option>
</select>
```

So is the id of main Question is 'MT001'

then the class names are

```
dec_MT001
dec_MT002
```

I have to check if the total some of the drop down for each Main question is 100 or not

I am trying to do this

```js
var validateWeightage = function(_classname) {

  //alert(_classname);

  var value = [];
  var sum = 0;

  $('.' + _classname).each(function() {

    if ($(this).val() != '' || $(this).val() != null)
      sum += parseInt($(this).val());

  });

  if (isNaN(sum) || sum <= 100) {
    //alert(sum);
    $('.' + _classname).addClass('label-danger');
  } else {
    $('.' + _classname).removeClass('label-danger').addClass('label-info');
  }

}

setInterval(function() {
  validateWeightage("dec_MT004");
}, 5000);
```

but this is not working ,

It is adding the CLass 'label-danger' even when The sub total is '100'

Any help would be appreciated

**Update**

here is a fiddle to support that

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/atg5m6ym/6369/)

Comment: Why are you doing it on an interval and not onchange?

Comment: What is mainQuestion? is that a form?

Comment: You're checking single class (single select) which don't have number larger then 100.

Comment: @epascarello yes I can do that as well ,

Comment: So what is `sum` when it is wrong?

Comment: @epascarello I will check it once again , i think its Nan value , Ill try to make a fiddle of it

Comment: @epascarello here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/atg5m6ym/6369/

Answer (score 0):

I think you change this area :

```
if(isNaN(sum) || sum < 100){
```

Or you defined global variables.

```
var value = [];
var sum = 0;

var validateWeightage = function(_classname) {

  //alert(_classname);



  $('.' + _classname).each(function() {

    if ($(this).val() != '' || $(this).val() != null)
      sum += parseInt($(this).val());

  });

  if (isNaN(sum) || sum <= 100) {
    //alert(sum);
    $('.' + _classname).addClass('label-danger');
  } else {
    $('.' + _classname).removeClass('label-danger').addClass('label-info');
  }

}

setInterval(function() {
  validateWeightage("dec_MT004");
}, 5000);
```

Comment: That is not an answer If you answer and it is correct, you would get enough rep to comment. Right now it is a comment. What does he need to change it TO?